# Acces object member with string name

Tags: javascript

I want to acces object member by my variable name. I have such code:

```
var name = "member"
var value = myObject.parameter.window[name];
value = myObject.parameter.eval(name);
```

So I have object `myObject` with member `parameter` and `parameter` has member named `member`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose your object look like this. and you need get member property,

```
var myObject = {
  parameter: {
    member: {}
  }
}
```

this code should solve you problem

```
var value = myObject.parameter[name];
```